# I have been getting an error loading a SpaCy model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

When I tried executing `nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`, 
I got an error `unpackb() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'`

Things that I have done already:

1. python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm. Linked successfully.
2. pip install msgpack. msgpack updated to 0.5.6
3. pip uninstall msgpack-python. uninstalled successfully.
4. conda list. 
       `msgpack-python            0.5.6            py36he980bc4_1    anaconda`
5. So I tried conda uninstall -c anaconda msgpack-python. But I get an error
       `RemoveError: This operation will remove conda without replacing it with
   another version of conda.`

Please help me out.

Comment: Please try installing from scratch in a clean environment and post the output of `pip list` after that.